# android user vs app config/preference files -- I'm confused

Tags: android, filesystems

[The docs talk about app-specific files and others like media files](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage).  Android is a multi-user environment, right?? It seems that in some instances at least, multiple users on a device all use the same instance of the app (google apps for instance).  The Docs talk about "Files meant for your app's use only" i.e. app-preferences.  How does android deal with user preferences for an app?  Are most apps just single-user?  In the case of a tablet for instance, does each user in the family have to install their own instance of an app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Android is a multi-user environment, right?

Yes.

> It seems that in some instances at least, multiple users on a device all use the same instance of the app (google apps for instance)

If you mean the same installed APK (or APK set), then yes.

> How does android deal with user preferences for an app?

If you mean `SharedPreferences`, they are stored on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/06/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). Each user gets their own view of internal storage, independent from that of any other registered user on the device. So, if there are 1,337 users, and each have used the app, there will be 1,337 `SharedPreferences` files, one per user.

> In the case of a tablet for instance, does each user in the family have to install their own instance of an app?

No. However, depending on circumstances, some users may not have access to all of the installed apps (e.g., restricted profiles).